# Python stuck at last program execution

Tags: python-3.x, buffer-overflow

I am new to Python and I think I broke my python :(

I was trying Sentdex's PyQt4 YouTube tutorial right [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU).

I made the changes from `PyQt4` to `PyQt5`. This is the code I was playing around. So I think, I messed up by printing the whole page on the console.

Now the output is:

```
Load finished
Look at you shinin!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is being shown for any code executed. That is python shows this code even if I try `print("hello")` in Visual code. I even tried to restart. Now like a virus, it is not clearing.

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    page = Page('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
    print js_test.text
    print (soup)
    #js_test = soup.find('div', class_='aqi-meter-panel')
    #display.popen.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: One more update. This problem seems to be occuring only when I use Visual Studio Code. If i directly use the command line, it is still working. Also I was using the below lines for experimenting with problems of montior error from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(600,600))
display.start()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so finally got the problem fixed..went manually inside the temp files in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local and started on a deletion rampage...removed many files and folder remotely related to python,vscode and conda...this  gave an error warning first time I executed my program again...then on subsequent run...no issue...python back to its normal self...surprised that I was not able to find any solution on the net for this.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).